# LAMP - Tool to create Layered PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, layered

Hi Do anyone know Good and CHEAPER tool we can use to create layered PDF in LAMP?
i came to know about PDFLib+PDI8 but thats €1590... but i am looking for cheaper option.. but must be same level to that PDFLib+pdi8.

Thanks in advance
Pravin P

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) ?

Comment: Currently i am using FPDF. but i think we can develop flat pdf files with that not layered. ( i am not aware if recent development allow that). PDFLib+pdi is one solution but very costly.. i am looking for something to replace that combination.

Thanks for quick reply.
Pravin P